# [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function on computed

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to divide a list of object into two rows the upper row and lower row using a simple computed function but I keep getting the above error. I've been looking for answer for half a day. I will appreciate any help.

index.vue

```
computed: {
    firstRow() {
      return this.data.filter((data, i) => index % 2 === 0)
    },
    secondRow() {
      return this.data.filter((data, i) => index % 2 !== 0)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.data = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }]
  },
```

index.vue template

```
<template>
 <div>
   {{ firstRow }}
    ------------
   {{ secondRow }}
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you share a working demo of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've declared your `data` item:

```js
data() {
  return {
    data: []
  }
}
```

Then, fix the typo in the filter which uses `index` instead of `i`:

```js
computed: {
  firstRow() {
    return this.data.filter((data, i) => i % 2 === 0)
  },
  secondRow() {
    return this.data.filter((data, i) => i % 2 !== 0)
  }
},
```

Or, if you meant to use the `id`:

```js
computed: {
  firstRow() {
    return this.data.filter((data, i) => data.id % 2 === 0)
  },
  secondRow() {
    return this.data.filter((data, i) => data.id % 2 !== 0)
  }
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/51yhnsj7/)

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so, please checkmark this answer and this will help other people as well. You can do so [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).  Or let me know if there's something unclear.